# Jquery events for controls generated after the load of the page

Tags: jquery

I have TextBoxes of a class, and on button click I append another element of the same class.

How can I make it that the new TextBox behaves like the rest of its class?

Example: **http://jsfiddle.net/GCQKE/**

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <input id="textbox1" type="text" class="textbox" />
    <input id="textbox2" type="text" class="textbox" />
    <input id="textbox4" type="text" class="textbox" />
</div>
<input type="button" class="append" value="Append new TextBox" />
```

JQUERY

```
$(".append").click(function (e) {
    $(".container").append("<input id='textbox3' type='text' class='textbox' />");
});


$(".textbox").click(function (e) {
    alert($(e.target).attr("id"));
});
```

When I click all the textboxes, I get the alert, exept for the one generated on button click. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO (jsfiddle updated)](http://jsfiddle.net/GCQKE/2/)**

You should do this by using the correct syntax for `.on()` for future elements by **binding the event to a parent that exists at the time the code is run** and giving it the selector of the children that you actually want the event to bind to.

```
$('.container').on('click', '.textbox', function() {
   //alert($(this).attr("id"));
   console.log(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

your `.click(...)` will only bind to elements that have that class on pageload,

if you want to bind a function to all elements of a class now or in the future (present on pageload or dynamically inserted), used jquery's delegate...

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

replace

```
$(".textbox").click(function (e) {
    alert($(e.target).attr("id"));
});
```

with

```
$('.container').delegate('.textbox', 'click', function(e){
    alert($(e.target).attr("id"));
});
```